# Freeing up memory allocated for a very long string (char*) in C?

Tags: c, string, memory-management, crash, malloc

Please, I need help for freeing up allocated memory for a really long string. I have tried to trim-down the code to this little piece which encompasses the problem I have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define N 6
#define E 1024

int M[N][N][N], R[N*N][N], C[N*N][N], F[N*N][N];

void init_rcf() {
    int i, j, k, p;

    p = 0;
    for(j=0; j<N; j++) {
        for(k=0; k<N; k++) {
            for(i=0; i<N; i++) 
                R[p][i] = M[i][j][k];
            p++;
        }
    }

    p = 0;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(k=0; k<N; k++) {
            for(j=0; j<N; j++)
                C[p][j] = M[i][j][k];
            p++;
        }
    }

    p = 0;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++) {
            for(k=0; k<N; k++)
                F[p][k] = M[i][j][k];
            p++;
        }
    }
}

char *bin(int n, int p) {
    int c, d, count;
    char *pointer;
    count = 0;
    pointer = (char*)malloc(p+1);

    for (c = p-1;c >= 0;c--) {
        d = n >> c;
        if (d & 1) 
            *(pointer+count) = 1 + '0';
        else 
            *(pointer+count) = 0 + '0';
        count++;
    }
    *(pointer+count) = '\0';
    return  pointer;
}

int f0(int n) {
    return ceil(log2(n+1)); 
}

int f1() {
    int sum, max = 0;
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++) {
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++) {
            for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++) {
                sum = M[i][j][k] + M[i+1][j][k]; 
                if (sum > max) 
                    max = sum; 
            }
        }   
    }
    return max;
}

int f2() {
    int sum, max = 0;
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++) {
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<N-1;j++) {
                sum = M[i][j][k] + M[i][j+1][k]; 
                if (sum > max) 
                    max = sum; 
            }
        }   
    }
    return max;
}

int f3() {
    int sum, max = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++) {
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            for(int k=0;k<N-1;k++) {
                sum = M[i][j][k] + M[i][j][k+1]; 
                if (sum > max) 
                    max = sum; 
            }
        }   
    }
    return max;
}

int f4() {
    int m1 = f1(),  m2 = f2(), m3 = f3(); 
    if ((m1 >= m2) && (m1 >= m3)) return m1;
    if ((m1 <= m2) && (m2 >= m3)) return m2;
    if ((m1 <= m3) && (m2 <= m3)) return m3;
}

char *g_fxn() {
    char *g = (char *) malloc(1 + (N*N*N)*3); 
    int k = f0(f4());

    init_rcf();
    strcpy(g,"");            
    for(int i=0; i<N*N; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++) 
            strcat(g,bin(R[i][j],k));
    for(int i=0; i<N*N; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++) 
            strcat(g,bin(C[i][j],k));
    for(int i=0; i<N*N; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++) 
            strcat(g,bin(F[i][j],k));
    return g;
}

void convert2bin(char *file_in) {
    const char *FILENAME_IN = file_in;
    const char FILENAME_OUT[] = "temp.txt";
    char c, d; 
    int k=0;

    FILE *infile;
    FILE *outfile;

    infile = fopen(FILENAME_IN, "rb");
    outfile = fopen(FILENAME_OUT, "w");
    if(infile == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Source file not found.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF){
        k++;
        unsigned n = (sizeof(c) * CHAR_BIT) - 1; 
        for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) { 
            int m = (c >> (n-i)) & 1; 
            d = '0'+m;          
            fwrite(&d, 1, sizeof(d), outfile);
        }
    }

    if (k < E) {
        d = '1';
        fwrite(&d, 1, sizeof(d), outfile);
        for (int i=k; i<=E; i++) { 
            d = '0';            
            fwrite(&d, 1, sizeof(d), outfile);
        }
    }

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
}

void digest() {
    const char *FILENAME_IN = "temp.txt";
    const char FILENAME_OUT[] = "digest.txt";

    int size = N*N*N; // size of message to construct N*N*N matrix
    char c, msg0[size], *msgf; 

    FILE *infile;
    FILE *outfile;

    infile = fopen(FILENAME_IN, "r");
    outfile = fopen(FILENAME_OUT, "wb");
    if(infile == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Source file \"temp.txt\" not found.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int quit = 0;
    while (quit == 0) {
        msgf = (char *) malloc(1 + (size)*3);
        strcpy(msgf, ""); 
        strcpy(msg0, "");
        int p = 0;
        while(((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) && (p < size)) {
            msg0[p++] = c;
        }

        if(c == EOF) quit = 1;
        if (p > 0) {
            if (p < size) {
                msg0[p] = '1';
                for(int i=p+1; i<size; i++) 
                    msg0[i] = '0';
            }

            for (int k=0; k<N; k++)
                for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
                    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                        c = msg0[i + N * (j + N * k)];
                        if (c == '0')
                            M[i][j][k] = 0;
                        else 
                            M[i][j][k] = 1;
                    }

            strcpy(msgf, g_fxn());             
            int q = 0;

            while (q<strlen(msgf)) {
                int d;
                char b = 0;
                for (int r=0; r<8; r++) {
                    if (msgf[q++] == '0') 
                        d = 0;
                    else 
                        d = 1;
                    b = ((b<<1) | d);
                }
                fwrite(&b, 1, 1, outfile);
                b = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    free(msgf);
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc!=2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Provide name of one source file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *clear_file = argv[1];

    convert2bin(clear_file);

    digest();

    printf("File successfully digested!\n");

    return(0);
}
```

This code works fine for input files of up to 27 bytes, but beyond that it crashes each time.

After trying to debug I discovered the issue lies on the `strcpy(msgf, g_fxn());` call to the function **g_fxn** and my guess is that problem there comes from the big chunk of memory allocated for the message but which seems not to be liberated after. I'm guessing this because the code works when there are less calls to **g_fxn** but crashes with more calls.

Anyone has any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: First of all always cjeck the malloc return. If NULL your pointer is not allocated.

Comment: your indentation is very confusing!

Comment: Change `c` in `convert2bin()` to `int c` nad re-write `unsigned n = (sizeof(c) * CHAR_BIT) - 1;`.

Comment: Indentation corrected (sorry)

Comment: `convert2bin()` was working fine but changing to `int c` makes it crash with an even smaller source file!

Comment: still the first lines are confusing (the innermost p++; seams to be connected to the before "for", unless you see the statement behind the "for"

Comment: @PeterMiehle Sorry, I didn't catch that one, it's all corrected now.

Comment: regarding this line: 'while((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF){'  'c' is defined as 'char' and fgetc() returns an int and EOF is an int.  Therefore, EOF will never be recognized (EOF 0s 0xFFFFFFFF and a char can only contain up to 0xFF(

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions).   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from every call to fopen() to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: When indenting code, never use tabs, because each editor/wordprocessor has different settings for tab widths/tab stops.   Suggest placing only one code statement per line, for readability by us humans

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  When asking about a runtime problem, post code that cleanly compiles. the macro CHAR_BIT is not defined (because the appropriate header file has not been #include'd.   The function f4() has a path that does not end with a 'return value;' statement.  this line: 'while (q<strlen(msgf)) {' and this line: 'or (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {' are comparing between a signed and a unsigned value.   the variable 'k' is unused in two of the functions.   Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled (for gcc, at a minimum use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  then fix the warnings.

Comment: These calls `strcat(g, ...` are called `N*N*N` times and `g` gets `N*N*N + 1` bytes allocated. So each call may not add more then an average of exactly `1` character to `g`. Is this the case? If not, then from a certain iteration on the program provokes undefined behaviour by writing beyond the memory allocated to `g` and  most likely sooner or later leads to a segmentation violation, the program "crashes".

Comment: The program might provoke memory issues, typically by writing out of the bounds of allocated memory. I advise to run it using a memory checker like Valgrind (https://valgrind.org) to debug this.

Comment: @user36329249 `while((c=fgetc(infile))!=EOF)` does work so I'm not really sure that's where the problem lies. Like I said the code works fine for very small input files (up to 25 bytes). Next, sorry, the error probably cropped in when I was trimming down the code to the bare minimum to highlight where it crashes. I have edited the code in the Question correct it so it should compile now.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the remarks concerning `malloc()` and code indenting (I have tried to "air up" the code a little). Also, I checked this: the function `f4()` does return for all paths, and I didn't find for which path it won't return a value!

Comment: @alk Thanks for the comment, the extra +1 is due to the '\0' character at the end of every string in C. My thinking is that the `strcat()` operation will always put a single '\0' but only at the end of the string making only +1 character in addition to 3 times N*N*N.

Comment: The question was not about the `+1` but about whether the `bin()` passed as argument to `strcat()` always and only returns a "string" with length of `1` (not taking into account the `0`-terminator). Becuase if this is **not** the case then `g` will overflow.

Comment: @alk Oops!!! I guess I missed that. You're totally right here, thanks for pointing that out. I think `g` does overflow in this case! I did not take into account the length of the string returned by `bin()`. I guess this means I'm going to have to allocate much bigger memory for the `g` variable. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks so much! (BTW I had never heard about Valgrind before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msgf gets allocated in the while loop of function digest() a lot of times:

```
msgf = (char *) malloc(1 + (size)*3);
```

But free() is only called once after the loop:

```
free(msgf);
```

This is at least one memory leak I found.

Comment: The `bin()` function also appears to allocate memory that is never freed.

Comment: No need to free the memory in bin() function, you can also free them after using the returned value (string). You have to store the returned pointer in a buffer variable for that, then use the buffer variable and free it afterwards (each time bin() is called).

Comment: @RhinoDevel Thanks for the remark, you're right, but I could not do otherwise. Freeing msgf within the while loop - just before closing the loop - makes it crash even for 1 byte input files!

Comment: @DavidLaPorte As for the memory allocated in the `bin()` function that is where I have the biggest problem, I can't free `g` because that is precisely what the function returns. I have got no idea how I can free the memory allocated in the `bin()` function...

Comment: @RhinoDevel thanks for that suggestion. One question though: does that mean I am going to have to use a global variable as buffer? I ask this because I think I won't be able to free it otherwise.

Comment: No. Add a variable to g_fxn(): char* binBuf = NULL; Before each strcat() call in the loops add binBuf = bin(...); Modify strcat() calls to strcat(g, binBuf); and add free(binBuf); after that. You know what to add for the "..." in bin(...) - do you? ;-)

Comment: :-) Sure I do! Thanks a lot @RhinoDevel, I had to add `binBuf = (char*)malloc(f0(f4())+1)` within each loop to get it working, so now it works for bigger input files. It still crashes for 1 kb files though, but I will try to apply the same technique in `digest()` for the calls to `g_fxn()` and see how that goes...

Comment: Well @RhinoDevel, looks like I rejoiced too soon, that does not work when applied to the function `digest()` for calls to `g_fxn()`. I'm stuck: it crashes with input files not even up to 80 bytes

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as the most helpful in terms of freeing up allocated memory. What actually solved the issue I was facing is the comment from @alk in the main comments section of the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions in which memory is allocated but not freed like in -

`char *g_fxn()`  and  `char *bin(int n, int p)`

### EDIT

As the pointers are returned in these functions you can use a `goto` statement.

Well see following example which just shows how to solve your problem -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char lol(char c[]);

char lol(char c[])
{ 
  char a[6]="hello";
  char *p=malloc(sizeof(a));
  p=a;
  memcpy(c,p,strlen(a));
  goto DONE;

  DONE:
  free(p);
  return c;
}

int main()
{
   char b[5];
   lol(b);
   printf("%s",b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ameyCU, this is exactly where I have a problem: in `g_fxn()` freeing the memory allocated for `msgf` inside the while loop makes it crash and in `bin()` I do not know how to free the memory allocated for the variable I am returning?!

Comment: @IT_guy Please check the edit.i tried ti solve your problem you can use similar logic in you program by modifying it .

Comment: thanks for this idea, I will explore it and see how it goes, though I'm not quite sure _how_ to adapt it in my code. Still, I will give it some thought.

Answer (score 0):

If a function allocates memory and returns the resulting pointer, not freeing the memory, then the calling function has to make sure that it's freed once it's no longer needed. In your `strcpy(msgf, g_fxn())` case this could look like this:

```
char *tmp = g_fxn();
strcpy(msgf, tmp);
free(tmp);
```

Generally, each time you get a pointer to memory from `malloc()` you have to later pass a pointer to that memory to `free()`, once it's no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for that @sth, I tried that too but it crashes for 1 byte input files in that case.